# Stop form refresh not working, on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I try to stop the refresh on my form when I use the `change` event.

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {

    $("input[type='file']").change(function () {
        console.log("on change ok");

        $("#modifier").submit(function (e) {

            console.log("on submit ok");
            /*
               treatment
            */
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="modifier" >
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="test" />
    <input type="file" name="upload" />
</form>
```

When picture is uploaded (`input[type='file']`), I'd like to submit it but I don't meed to refresh my page and do some treatment.

Comment: You need to use AJAX to achieve this behaviour. See the answer I marked for more information.

Comment: Also note: Wiring up one event handler inside another event handler, is generally a sign of something wrong.